# How to filter each row dropdown values in Angular Ui Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I started to work with ui-grid a few time ago so i'm having some problems.
I would like to filter the options in dropdown of every row of the grid.
I can filter the values and show it in the dropdown field but when i click in dropdown only appear undefined values. What can i do to solve this problem?
I've tried so many things but i can't find the solution.

Here is the plunker

http://embed.plnkr.co/HMsq4OasNs50ywJuI3DS/

Thanks

Comment: Kudos to you for including a plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1pEPY7GpPMlQ3V1nr6KL?p=preview).

In summary, I changed up the column definition to use editDropdownOptionsFunction instead of the combination of editDropdownOptionsArray and cellFilter. According to the documentation,

> cellFilter is a filter to apply to the content of each cell

... so that doesn't seem like what you were trying to achieve.

Also, changed the periodos definition for rowEntity.sindicato === 1 to be an array rather than an object.

```
  editDropdownOptionsFunction: function(rowEntity, colDef) {
    console.log(rowEntity);

    if (rowEntity.sindicato === 1) {
      periodos = [{
        id: 1,
        value: 'teste1'
      }];
    } else if (rowEntity.sindicato === 2) {

      periodos = [{
        id: 2,
        value: 'test2'
      }, {
        id: 5,
        value: 'test5'
      }];
    } else {
      periodos = [{
        id: 3,
        value: 'test3'
      }, {
        id: 6,
        value: 'test6'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        value: 'test4'
      }];

    }

    return periodos;

  }
```

Comment: Cool.  Glad that helped.

Comment: Done. Thank for your very simple solution,  all things make the sense now.